# probability of sales / reasonable estimate

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am stuck on trying to understand what seems like a simple problem!

"A store manager predicts that his sales for a certain day of the week will be $\$150,000.00$. An independent assessor following the store's day-to-day sales says that the probability of the store's sales for this same day being $\geq \$150,000$ is $0.35$. Therefore, what is a more reasonable estimate for the store's sales for the day?"

The only thing I could think of was to compute $150000 \cdot 0.35 = 52500$, but I don't know why this should be correct. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that the assessor is saying that the sales are more likely than not to be above $150k.

Comment: I think at least you went the wrong way. With greater than 50-50 chance, of being greater than $150k, it should be higher, right?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I edited it, the probability is 35%.

Comment: If the assessor had said 50%, what would you have said? 49%? 51%?

Comment: @Joffan I don't understand. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Sorry, I was being a little indirect. Clearly if the assessor had said 50%, the manager's estimate is essentially validated - we shouldn't change it. Ross identifies my principal concern, that there really isn't enough information to decide - even if we think the assessor is god-like accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not enough information to answer the problem.  If we accept the assessor's statement as truth, it could be that the store sells $149,000$ on $65\%$ of the days and $1,000,000$ on $35\%$ of the days.  They could sell nothing on $65%$ of the days and $150,001$ on $35\%$ of the days.  We could easily come up with a distribution where the expected sales are truly $150,000$ even though the store falls short $65\%$ of the time.

Comment: Such a distribution: take on the values $149,999$ and $150,000 + 13/7$ with probability $1-.35$ and $.35$, respectively. The expected value is exactly $150,000$, yet the probability of exceeding $150,000$ is $.35$.

Comment: Extremely likely true for stores where some sales items are much higher value. A regular sales rhythm and the occasional bonanza.